# VPN on server for certain outgoing connections

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

I have a server running openvpn for outgoing connections. However, once I start openvpn, I lose SSH, HTTP access to the server's IP. This is expected I guess, but is there a way to circumvent the VPN connection when connecting to these ports?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a static route to the Server's address to go through eth0, wlan0, etc.  This should bypass the tunnel interface explicitly.  If you need to do this on a port level, try IPTABLES

**Linux**

```
inet_route [-vF] add {-host|-net} Target[/prefix] [gw Gw] [metric M]
                          [netmask N] [mss Mss] [window W] [irtt I]
                          [mod] [dyn] [reinstate] [[dev] If]
```

**Windows**

```
route ADD 157.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0  157.55.80.1 METRIC 3 IF 2
       destination^      ^mask      ^gateway     metric^    ^
                                                   Interface^
If IF is not given, it tries to find the best interface for a given
gateway.
```